# How to add a powerpoint presentation in web

Tags: javascript, html, web, powerpoint

I have this task to make an iframe of a presentation appear on an click. then you can control that presentation, like the page you want or go forward and backward.
The problem is I can't use the cloud solutions, because the data should be on premises.
I've thought about converting it to a video, it would be easier to control it and also to keep the animations.
I've also thought about converting it to a pdf file and then show the slides, like slideshare does in this [Example](https://fr.slideshare.net/HSCIC/java-script-ppt).
Is there anyway I can use the ppt directly or even convert it to another format that would be optimal and user friendly, if so, how? is there any APIs or Javascript libraries? what would you recommend?

Comment: Can't you use a framework like [Reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) ?

Comment: Reveal.js only gives you the ability to make new presentations for HTML , if you want to put an existent presentation in ppt , you would have to do it all over again so that it would be compatible with the framework .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i've found a solution of this, i want to share it with you.

If you need to present a ppt-like presentation on web without using the cloud solutions.

**The first one is used to keep animation of the presentation:**

I converted the ppt to a video , and then used Video.js library that enables you full control over the video.

I've desactivated the control of the video and made my own controls with Html and css. GoForward , Backwards or pause or play or restart the presentation.

i was able to pick and to know the slide i'm on and how much time in every slide by dividing the full time of the video by the number of slides i have in it. (if we suppose they have equal time).

**The Second one is used for better quality but no animation:** by converting the PPT to PDF.